# Database modification after paypal payment confirmation

Tags: javascript, paypal, sqlalchemy, paypal-sandbox

i am setting up paypal payments on my website and i want to check wether the user has already payed or not.
So my idea is to have a boolean in my sqlalchemy database (that contains all the users) set to false if the user hasn't payed yet and if the user pays set it to True.

This is the script that checks the payment on approve (it is a script provided by Paypal)

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
  // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
  return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
    // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
  });
```

Is there any way to use that script so when the transaction succeeds it modifies the boolean of my database to True?
My app is a python app with flask and sqlalchemy.
Sorry if this is a noob question but there is not much paypal documentation on this topic and I dont know a lot of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Client side code should not be initiating things that modify your database and mark things as paid.

Please switch to a proper server-side API capture.

See this front-end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .

On your backend server you will need to create 2 corresponding routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction', one for 'Capture Transaction'.  See the guide at: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/